# listView SetAdaptor is causing crash at app start

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am playing around with Monodroid, trying to set an adaptor to a listview at start up. I have a bunch of controls on the screen, what I am trying to do is when the button is clicked an item goes into the listview.

I don't get any error from the debugger, just a "Unfortunately Application1 has stopped", which makes it hard to work out what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    List<string> items = new List<string>();
    ArrayAdapter<string> adaptor;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        int i = 0;

        items.Add("Hello world");
        adaptor = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,
            Resource.Id.listView1,
            items);

        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        ListView listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
        listView.SetAdapter(adaptor);

        button.Click += delegate
        {
            items.Add("Hello " + ++i);
            adaptor.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        };
    }
}
```

Upon a comment I found the Device Log with the following:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050003 type #0x12 is not valid
```

This is the ID for the listview in Resource.Designer.cs

```
public const int listView1 = 2131034115;
```

The listview is declared like this:

```
    <ListView
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        p1:layout_height="fill_parent"
        p1:id="@+id/listView1"
        p1:layout_marginBottom="70dp" />
```

Comment: As a debugging reference: LogCat will tell you exactly which line of code in your application caused the crash and the reason for the fault.. like a null pointer.. index out of range.. etc. this is found under the DDMS tab in eclipse

Comment: @dymmeh Thanks I didn't know about it, found it in VS. Got closer to the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out after reading through the documentation. When instantiating the ArrayAdapter it must be instantiated with reference to Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1 or another list item resource, rather than the listview itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this code:

```
mForecastAdapter =
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.mymain,
                   R.id.list_view_forecast, 
                    foreCastArray
    );
```

Then after reading your post, I changed it to:

```
 mForecastAdapter =
     new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                   // R.id.list_view_forecast, 
                    foreCastArray
     );
```

Used the simple list view **and** removed the list view id. This worked.